# WooCommerce Cart - Group Products By Category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to group my products in the woocommerce cart by category so that it display as

**Category 1** - Product 1, Product 2.

**Category 2** - Product 1, Product 2 etc

The loop in cart.php pulls through all products at the same time:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
```

is there a way to only pull through products from one category? Something like:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart(['product_cat']->'football') as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
```

And then to repeat the loop again for each of the categories?

Thanks for the help - appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function inside the foreach loop like:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    if( has_term( array('football'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much , greatly appreciated

Comment: @Matt-SalusaCommunity If this answer answers your question, you could please [accept](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer, Thank you.

Comment: That really helped me! Thanks a lot